# C++: Passing classes as argument to methods of other classes

Tags: c++, function, class, arguments

I want to pass a class pointer to a function which is a member of another class and it won't work. If the function `fill_packet` is not a member of any class, the code compiles without problems:

```
// WORKS FINE:

class Packet{
private:
  char *contents;

public:
  void pack();
};

void fill_packet(Packet *a){
  a->pack();
};
```

However, if the function `fill_packet` is inside another class (here *Worker*), it suddenly does no longer compile as soon as I try to access a method of `a`.

```
// WON'T COMPILE:
// error: ‘Packet’ has not been declared

class Worker{
public:
  void fill_packet(Packet *a){
    a->pack();
  };
};

class Packet{
private:
  char *contents;

public:
  void pack();
};
```

Can someone give me insight? thanks in advance

Comment: what you have posted here is fine.  must be something else wrong.

Comment: Add more information.  Where do you call fill_packet?  Are you calling it on a valid worker with a valid pack?  What error message do you get when you try to compile?

Comment: Sounds like fill_packet may want to be static. Then it should work as well.

Comment: **Don't use pointers to pass-by-reference, use references**

Comment: [Example that uses pass-by-reference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87e45bec31799e9a)

Comment: When you say "WON'T COMPILE:" is what follows in the same header file?

Comment: Post your example with include and main so that a compile can be attempted. I bet many guys here will see the problem in maximum five seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the Packet class is defined before the Worker class, here is a full test:

```
#include <iostream>

class Packet {
private:
    char *contents;

public:
    void pack() {
        this->contents = "Some text";
    }
    char * getContents() {
        return this->contents;
    }
};

class Worker {
public:
    void fill_packet(Packet *a) {
        a->pack();
    }
};


int main() {
    Packet * packet =  new Packet;
    Worker worker;
    worker.fill_packet(packet);

    std::cout << packet->getContents() << std::endl;

    delete packet;
    return 0;
}
```

if you run this test you will got the output you expect.

Comment: I thought the order of declaration does not matter as long as both are declared in the Same Region. This helped me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Oh I get it now. That's one of the purposes of using headers. If I define prototypes of classes and functions in headers and include them at the beginning of a cpp file, in this case main.cpp, the order of declaration does not matter as all names are already known.

Answer (score 3):

It might be the case where Worker is included somewhere else before the declaration of 'Packet'. To fix this you can tell the compiler that the class Packed exists when you declare 'Worker', and the implementation of 'fill_packet' need to be put somewhere where both classes are declared;

something like this:

```
class Packet;
class Worker{
public:
  void fill_packet(Packet *a);
};

//in a cpp file:
void Worker::fill_packet(Packet *a){
    a->pack();
};
```

Hope this helps,
Raxvan.

Comment: and maybe #include the header file that defines Packet in this cpp file?

Comment: yes , in a place where both classes are defined , if in a cpp then the cpp needs to include both declarations.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it does compile!

maybe you have defined the class in a header which you did not include?

Comment: This is not an answer, its a comment, I think

Comment: Oh you are absolutely right. I defined a header in earlier attempt and forgot about it. I would accept yours as a second answer if I could...

Answer (score 1):

If your code goes like this

```
Packet mPacket;
Worker mWorker;
mWorker.fill_packet(&mPacket);
```

this should work.

On the other hand

```
Worker.fill_packet(&mPacket);
```

will not work, unless you declare

```
class Worker{
public:
  static void fill_packet(Packet *a){
    a->pack();
  };
};
```

Edit: note, the compiler error doesn't make sense from the code snippet you posted.

Comment: yeah it didnt make Sense to me either. Grim's and Rawdan's answer solved it for me though. I think this particular error came from a header which I forgot to Update.